# Jitsi Meet server

Tags: flutter, jitsi, jitsi-meet

Using jitsi_meet_wrapper in flutter and it's working fine but when I'm creating a meet I'm being put into lobby where it says you'll join when owner gives you access. I saw a solution where I was suggested to change server url from default to one of the community instances from this link - jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/community/community-instances.   But this link is no longer active and has no community instances. How do I solve this problem

I want to replace default server url of jitsi meet with some community instance.  Help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.